# manage a return url in form authentication

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, form-authentication

I have an ASP MVC 5 web site, I want to manage the return url to redirect the user to the last requested page, but when the user login, then log of before the hole page is loaded (some parts of the pages are loaded asynchronously), then if He tries to login again, he'll be redirected to the one of partial content, or sometime he is redirected to load an image, or js file.
How can I controlle if the return url is requested by user or by the browser ( from the first load).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding the Authorize attribute :

```
 public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public CompanyServiceBase CompanyService { get; set; }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string returnUrl = null;
                var controller = (System.Web.Mvc.Controller)filterContext.Controller;
                if (!controller.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    returnUrl = controller.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                }

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary()
            {
                { "client", filterContext.RouteData.Values[ "client" ] },
                { "controller", "Account" },
                { "action", "Login" },
                { "ReturnUrl", returnUrl }
            });
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "AccessDenied", controller = "Main" }));
            }
        }
```